# Is there a sharp point at which the concept of electromagnetic force disappears?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics

This is a question related to the crossover between classical and quantum physics. In quantum physics, we speak of a Hamiltonian - never of forces - yet in introductory courses, it’s common to speak of forces acting on single particles (the “test” charge). Such single particles are clearly quantum objects, but is it always necessary to treat them as such? Or are simple cases involving isolated particles in constant fields safely treated as classical?

As far as I understand, speaking of a field like $\vec{E}$ or $\vec{B}$ would require a classical treatment - for example, I remember one of my graduate texts doing something like a Fourier transform after finding the potential energy of the quantum field in momentum space to produce the classical field result. And sure, Maxwell’s equations have the same form (in terms of $F^{\mu\nu}$) whether classical or quantum, but the Coulomb and Biot-Savart force laws seem to be strictly classical. Are statements about single particles under the influence of classical fields misguided or misleading? Is there a well-grounded definition for quantum particles in a classical context, or are they entirely different entities?

Comment: Force implies acceleration which implies a trajectory. But quantum particles don’t have trajectories because of the uncertainty principle. I think you’re really asking about the dividing line between classical physics and quantum physics.

Comment: Yes, that is what I’m asking about. But I don’t see how the uncertainty principle precludes trajectories.

Comment: A trajectory for a particle implies a definite position and momentum for the particle at each point along the trajectory. The HUP doesn’t allow both $\vec x$ and $\vec p$ to have definite values.

Comment: Good point. So then, is the concept of test charge fundamentally wrong?

Comment: I’d say that test charges are a classical concept. I’ve never seen a quantum textbook talk about them. For me, they are a way to initially grasp what a field is, in terms of simpler concepts like forces on test charges, but then we promote fields to primary status in quantum field theory. We take them as given, and use them to compute things like scattering cross sections, rather than “explaining” them.

Comment: Okay. I guess we can’t really “explain” things as fundamental as quantum fields, anyway. Funny how pedagogy gets smacked in the face by reality.